# Get width of a group element using python svgwrite library

Tags: python, svg, svgwrite

I am using python library svgwrite to generate svg file. I have to put two lines of text exactly at the center of a rectangle. The texts should be left aligned. The width and height of the rectangle is known. I inserted two text lines inside a group container, and aligned them by setting their 'text_anchor' attribute to 'start', and x position to 0. Here is the code:

```
svg = svgwrite.Drawing(size=(210*mm, 297*mm), viewBox=('0 0 210 297'))
rect_width = 80
rect_height = 25
rect = svg.rect(insert=(0, 0), size=(rect_width, rect_height), fill='none', stroke='red', stroke_width=1)
font_size = 6 #in mm
style = "font-family:Arial; font-size:%i" % (font_size)
text_1 = svg.text('Line 1', insert=(0,0), style=style, text_anchor='start', dominant_baseline='hanging')
text_2 = svg.text('Longer Line 2', insert=(0, font_size), style=style, text_anchor='start', dominant_baseline='hanging')
text_group = svg.g()
text_group.add(text_1)
text_group.add(text_2)
x_pos = rect_width/2
y_pos = rect_height/2-font_size
text_group.translate(x_pos, y_pos)
svg.add(rect)
svg.add(text_group)
```

The output is shown here:
[See generated SVG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWuxR.png)

It seems the vertical position of 'text_group' is OK (at the center). But Horizontal position should be more to the left. This is achievable if I can get the width of 'text_group', and modify 'x_pos':

```
x_pos = rect_width/2 - text_group_width/2
```

I couldn't find any way to get the width of the text group in svgwrite. Is there any method to get the width, or if there is any alternative solution to this problem?

Comment: you'd need to use a rendering engine to layout the SVG. svgwrite is just an XML writer, it operates at the markup level.

Comment: Any suggestion for SVG rendering engine that goes well with Python?

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonWebKit

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into that.

Answer (score 0):

I found this

`svg.text(style="text-anchor:middle")`

to be useful for centrally aligning text